# emails from gmail account not syncing

Tags: settings, display, pantheon-mail

Since yesterday emails from gmail account are not being downloaded at all - I have elementary OS installed on another laptop and I have experienced no problems. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try in terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

If it will not solve the issue remove account from pantheon mail. Remove it via App Center. Then install Thunderbird in App Center.